# Several identities regarding cyclotomic polynomials.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, cyclotomic-polynomials

- $\Phi_n(x^r) = \Phi_{nr}(x)$ where $r$ is a positive integer and if prime number $p|r$ then $p|n$.
- $\Phi_n(x^{ps}) = \Phi_{n}(x^s)\Phi_{pn}(x^s)$ where $p$ is a prime number, $p\nmid n$ and $s$ is a positive integer.
- $\Phi_n(x) = \Phi_{p_1 \dots p_k}(x^{np_1^{-1} \dots p_k^{-1}})$ where n is a positive integer and $p_1,\dots, p_k$ are different prime factors of $n$.

First I tried to prove the first identity. 
Using the definition of cyclotomic polynomial, we have $$\Phi_{nr}(x) = \prod_{1\le k \le nr\\ (k,nr)=1} (x-e^{\frac{2k\pi}{nr}\ i})$$ and
$$\Phi_n(x^r) = \prod_{1\le k \le n \\ (k,n)=1} (x^r-e^{\frac{2k\pi}{n}\ i})$$

We know that when $1\le k \le n$, $(k,n)=1 \Leftrightarrow (k,nr)=1$.
How can I proceed from here?
Or is there any reference regarding these identities?

Comment: There have been many similar questions here on MSE, have a look. Many identities are given at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial#Examples), see "Easy cases for computation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some ideas. With all of these we start from

$$\Phi_n(x) = \prod_{d|n} (x^d-1)^{\mu(n/d)}.$$

For the first one we get with  the prime factors of $r$ being a subset
of those of $n$ that

$$\Phi_{rn}(x) = \prod_{d|rn} (x^{d}-1)^{\mu(rn/d)}
= \prod_{d|rn} (x^{rn/d}-1)^{\mu(d)}.$$

Now as $r$ does not contribute  any extra prime factors and the Mobius
function is restricting terms this becomes

$$\prod_{d|n} (x^{rn/d}-1)^{\mu(d)} = \Phi_n(x^r).$$

For the second one we get with $p$ a prime not dividing $n$ that

$$\Phi_n(x^{ps}) = \prod_{d|n} (x^{psd}-1)^{\mu(n/d)}
= \prod_{d|pn \wedge p|d } (x^{sd}-1)^{\mu(n/(d/p))}
\\ = \prod_{d|pn \wedge p|d } (x^{sd}-1)^{\mu(pn/d)}
= \prod_{d|pn} (x^{sd}-1)^{\mu(pn/d)}
\prod_{d|n} (x^{sd}-1)^{-\mu(pn/d)}
\\ = \Phi_{pn}(x^s) \prod_{d|n} (x^{sd}-1)^{\mu(n/d)}
= \Phi_{pn}(x^s) \Phi_{n}(x^s).$$

For the third one we again have

$$\Phi_n(x) = \prod_{d|n} (x^{n/d}-1)^{\mu(d)}.$$

With $\mu(d)$ zero when $n$ is not squarefree this becomes

$$\prod_{d|p_1\cdots p_k} (x^{n/d}-1)^{\mu(d)}.$$

Now in  this last product  $n/d$ can  be obtained by  decrementing the
power of  zero, one or more  of the prime  factors of $n$ by  one.  In
other  words it  is obtained  by  multiplying $n/p_1\cdots  p_k$ by  a
divisor $f$  of $p_1\cdots p_k.$  We then find  $d$ by solving  $n/d =
(n/p_1\cdots p_k)  f$ to get  $d = p_1\cdots p_k/f.$  Substitute these
into the formula to obtain

$$\prod_{f|p_1\cdots p_k}
(x^{(n/p_1\cdots p_k) f}-1)^{\mu(p_1\cdots p_k/f)}.$$

This is $\Phi_{p_1\cdots p_k}(x^{n/p_1\cdots p_k})$ by inspection.

Comment: Can you kindly explain how $ \prod_{d|rn} (x^{rn/d}-1)^{\mu(d)}= \prod_{d|n} (x^{rn/d}-1)^{\mu(d)}$ holds in the first part of your solution, given that each prime divisor of $r$ is also a divisor of $n$?

Comment: The divisor $d$ only makes a non-unit contribution through $\mu(d)$ for products of primes. But multiplying by $r$ does not introduce new primes so all products of primes that contribute are covered by the divisors of $n$.